# How to unselect one and multiple selected date in Fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript

I am using full calendar js in my code. I am able to select multiple dates in the calendar but I am not able to unselect the selected dates. Where do I need to changes in my code?

**IN HTML FILE**

```
    <div class ="main-container fullcalendar-booking-course unselectCancel">
        <div id="calendar"></div>
    </div>
```

**IN MY JS FILE**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                getFullCalendar();
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function getFullCalendar(){
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                    header: { 
                        left: 'prev,next',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek'
                    },
                    views: {
                        month: {
                          titleFormat: 'YYYY, MM, DD'
                        }
                    },
                    validRange: function(nowDate) {
                        return {
                          start: nowDate,
                          end: nowDate.clone().add(1, 'months')
                        };
                    },
                    navLinks: true,
                    selectable: true,
                    selectHelper: true,

                    select: function(start, end) {
                        startDate = moment(new Date(start)).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
                        endDate = moment(new Date(end)).format("MM-DD-YYYY");

                        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', [{
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            rendering: 'background',
                            block: true,
                        }]);

                        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
                    },

                    selectOverlap: function(event) {
                        return ! event.block;
                    },

                    editable: true,
                    eventLimit: true,
                    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback){

                    },
                    eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {

                    },

                    loading: function(bool) {
                        $('#loading').toggle(bool);
                    },

                    eventRender: function(event, element){

                    },

                    eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
                        var quantity = $('.fc-bgevent').length;
                        $("#quantity").val(quantity);
                    },

                }); 
            }

        </script>
```

**NOTE:**

I am using fullcalendar js file and CSS file. I have initialized the function in the document ready function. I need to unselect the selected dates. I can select multiple dates but unable to unselect the dates.

Comment: can you add the corresponding html code?

Comment: I have added please have a look into it

Comment: If that is indeed your content from a .js-file, it's invalid. <script>-tag is a html-element  and it can not be used in javascript-file. Also you are missing closing brackets from your ready-function callback.

Comment: Ok from next time i will take care of this @Halfer